# Error deploy project Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I use commands `ng build --prod` or `ng build --prod --aot` for production my projects
after connected file in document index.html -> errors occur:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
        at vendor.bundle.js:1
```

and

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
>     at r (inline.fc1c1a5….bundle.js:1)
>     at Object.585 (main.caf6b13….bundle.js:11)
>     at r (inline.fc1c1a5….bundle.js:1)
> ```

Previously everything worked fine...
thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "`after connected file in document index.html`"?

Comment: <link href="stylesheets/styles.d044b3fec6aa1d9717de.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/vendor.fddd64a8c6697d89b43b.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/inline.fc1c1a59deb81aeb3ac7.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/main.caf6b13d47e1a8b77d9e.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: webpackJsonp is not defined

Comment: that shouldnt be in your index.html